# How to do a simple read POST data in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, http, post, node.js

I've used this code to read the querystring ?name=Jeremy ...can anyone tell me how to do this with post data? also with json?

```
var http = require('http'), url = require('url');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    var urlObj = url.parse(request.url, true);
    response.write("Hello " + urlObj.query["name"] + "!\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 20):

You have to handle [data](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/http.html#event_data_) and [end](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/http.html#event_end_) events of [http.ServerRequest](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/http.html#http.ServerRequest) object. Example:

```
var util = require("util"),
    http = require('http'), 
     url = require('url'),
      qs = require('querystring');

...

// this is inside path which handles your HTTP POST method request
if(request.method === "POST") {
    var data = "";

    request.on("data", function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });

    request.on("end", function() {
        util.log("raw: " + data);

        var json = qs.parse(data);

        util.log("json: " + json);
    });
}
```

[Here](http://www.toxiccoma.com/random/nodejs-0195-http-post-handling-of-form-data) is an article on this topic with example (with too old version of node.js so it might not work, but the principle is the same).

Comment: I'm googling and I noticed your answer is from a year ago... is this still accurate? Also, I'm using express, which clearly isn't being used here

Comment: The problem here is that the response will not be correctly formatted JSON.